# How to convert a complex MySQL Query to Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create a weighted search using doctrine. This is how i do it in straight sql. Im wondering how i would convert it to us the doctrine2 methods. I am trying to do this search using symfony2.

Also if there is a better way to do this I am open to that to. Thanks.

```
"SELECT   *,
    IF(`name` LIKE "%$searchterm%",  20,
    IF(`name` LIKE "%$searchterm%", 10, 0)) +
    IF(`address` LIKE "%$searchterm%", 5,  0) +
    IF(`city`   LIKE "%$searchterm%", 1,  0)
    AS `weight`
 FROM `table_name`
 WHERE
     (`name` LIKE "%$searchterm%" OR
      `address` LIKE "%$searchterm%" OR
      `city`  LIKE "%$searchterm%")
 ORDER BY `weight` DESC
 LIMIT 20"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it can be done using `DQL`. Doctrine does not support `IF` statement. But same functionality can be achieved by `CASE` statement. Sample `DQL` is given bellow,

```
$dql = "SELECT t, 
          (CASE 
            WHEN (t.name LIKE :searchterm) THEN 10 
            ELSE 0
          END) + 
          (CASE 
            WHEN (t.address LIKE :searchterm) THEN 5 
            ELSE 0
          END) + 
          (CASE 
            WHEN (t.city LIKE :searchterm) THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
          END)
          AS weight 
        FROM YourBundleName:TableName t 
        WHERE 
          t.name LIKE :searchterm OR 
          t.address LIKE :searchterm OR 
          t.city LIKE :searchterm
        ORDER BY weight DESC
      ";
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
  ->setFirstResult(0)
  ->setMaxResults(20)
  ->setParameter('searchterm' , $searchterm)
  ;
```

Comment: Thank you that is working almost perfectly, the only thing that i need to know how to do is to have it do the LIKE search with the wildcards %. I tried %:searchterm% but it didnt like that.

Comment: nevermind i got it. just had to change ->setParameter('searchterm' , $searchterm) to  ->setParameter('searchterm' , '%'.$searchterm.'%')

Comment: The `CASE` syntax also works with Doctrine2 query builder. Thanks a lot.